# CometD in Salesforce Mobile?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, cometd, empapi

I have an app using empApi for desktop subscription to a Platform Event, and the version for Communities replaces empApi with cometD.

I'm struggling to find an option for Salesforce Mobile. empApi docs explicitly state it doesn't support Mobile (and I also tested it just in case... no-go.) CometD also doesn't seem to work in Mobile.

Any ideas on another way to subscribe to a platform event from Salesforce Mobile? I'd hate to have to implement periodic polling...

Comment: Push notifications?

Comment: @PhilW can you use Apex to receive a push notification?